# Jackson: Printing Values as Keys in the JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

Normally what we do in Jackson to print a class as JSON object is to define getter and setter like

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;

    public myClass(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public Integer getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public Integer getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setA(Integer a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

and this will return `{"a":1,"b":2}`

But can I get output as `{1:2}` instead of what I am getting before?

Comment: `{1:2}` it is not valid `JSON`. `{"1":2}` it is a valid `JSON`. Which version you want to print?

Comment: Okay, well I mean to convert the original JSON output to what I desired and since all my codes are using Strings (except this example code) i can skip this error;

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you need to write own code and pass accordingly. But output you showed is standard json format which you cannot change, but definitely you can change it with code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care that output `JSON` is not valid you can write custom serializer for your `POJO` class. It could look like this:

```
class MyClassJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(MyClass myClass, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartObject();

        generator.writeRaw(myClass.getA() + ":" + myClass.getB());

        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Using:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyClassJsonSerializer.class)
class MyClass {
....
}
```

Since now, your `POJO` should be serialized to desired output.